# wchar_t pointer manipulation - How to check whether it is ended with L".xls"

Tags: c

I am using C. I have a wchar_t pointer which pointing a a file path.

I was wondering, how I can check, whether it is ended with L".xls"?

Any function call I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that the string is at least 4 long
- See if the last 4 `wchar_t` are ".xls"

Thus, this should be it:

`if(wcslen(str) >= 4 && wcscmp(str + wcslen(str) - 4, L".xls") == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`wcsstr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/wcsstr.html).

Comment: That won't help with something like `file.xls.old`

Comment: You are correct there ... `wchar_t *r = wcsstr(str, L".xls"); if (r && r[4] == L'\0') { ... }` is the complete answer.  `wcsstr` is the only function that you need to call though ;)

Comment: For precisely what caf mentioned, `wcsstr` is not the function needed here. If the string has a premature `.xls` in it, wcsstr returns info on that, instead of what's at the end of the string, which is what we're really interested in.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. You could put it in a for loop (`for (r=str; r && Wcslen(r)!=4; r=wcsstr(str, L".xls"));` or such but when you could just do like the accepted answer, *why*?